# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I am learning `Redux` from https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/react-redux-react-router-es6/table-of-contents but I am stuck at some point. When I am trying to map my courses in `CoursePage.js` then it is showing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf6iY.png) error, The prop `courses` is marked as required in `CoursesPage`, but its value is `undefined`.
and:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

Here's the code

CoursePage.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as courseAction from "../../redux/actions/courseAction";

class CoursePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this);
    this.state = {
      course: {
        title: "",
      },
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const course = { ...this.state.course, title: event.target.value };
    this.setState({ course });
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.createCourse(this.state.course);
    // alert(this.state.course.title);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
            <div className="container">
              <h1 className="display-4">Course Page</h1>
              <form className="mt-4" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  value={this.state.course.title}
                />

                <input type="submit" value="Add" />

                {this.props.course.map((course) => (
                  <div key={course.title}>{course.title}</div>
                ))}

              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    course: state.course,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    createCourse: (course) => dispatch(courseAction.createCourse(course)),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CoursePage);
```

courseReducer.js

```
import * as types from "../actions/actionTypes";

export default function courseReducer(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.CREATE_COURSE:
      return [...state, { ...action.course }];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The state called `this.state.course` is an `{}` and that's the reason why you cannot run `.map()` on it. It can handle arrays only. Instead probably you want to show up `title` for the course then you don't need `.map()`.

Try the following only:

```
<div>{this.state.course.title}</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few minor issues here, that need fixing to bring you on the right track.

Your `mapStateToProps` refers to `course`, not `courses`. And if you want it to refer to `courses` then you need to update how the `CREATE_COURSE` action works in your reducer.

To fix the crash causing bug you'll need to add an `initialState` so that `courses` isn't undefined. Since it's ok to map through an empty array, but you can't map through `undefined`.

Update your `courseReducer` to the following:

```
import * as types from "../actions/actionTypes";

const initialState = {
  courses: []
}

export default function courseReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.CREATE_COURSE:
      return { ...state, courses: [...state.courses, action.course] };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And then make this change to your `mapStateToProps`:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    courses: state.courses,
  };
}
```

Finally change this bit of code from `this.props.course` to `this.props.courses`:

```
{this.props.courses.map((course) => (
  <div key={course.title}>{course.title}</div>
))}
```

Now your app should work as intended.

Comment: ./src/redux/reducers/courseReducer.js
  Line 8:35:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

   6 |   switch (action.type) {
   7 |     case types.CREATE_COURSE:
>  8 |     return [...state, courses: [...state.courses, action.course] ];
     |                                   ^
   9 |    default:
  10 |      return state;
  11 |   }

Comment: My bad, my answer had a syntax error, fixed it :). Give it a shot now.

Comment: That's because you left out your import line, I thought you'd have included that. I'll update my answer to include that.